# Confusion with drawing a bitmap from target to destination

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am looking for "CUTTING OUT" a 200x200 size of bitmap, from x=100, y=100 out of a Source bitmap which is 500x500 . Here is my code :

```
  var tempData:BitmapData 
  var tempBitmap:Bitmap ;
tempData = new BitmapData(500, 500,false, 0xffffff);

tempBitmap  = new Bitmap(tempData);

tempData.draw(original,null, null, null, new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200),true);
```

Works well, BUT,

the problem is that it draws from (0,0 ) to ( 100+200, 100+200 ). However it clips from (0,0) to (100,100). Thus the size is bigger than 200x200, no matter the other part is plain white.

I need drawing should start from 100,100 to 300,300 . So that the movieclip i place this bitmap into must have a size of 200x200. It should not show any plain white area. But only the content of the source bitmap from x=100, y=100 to x=300, y= 300

Kindly feel free to comment, if my explanation is still not clear.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're copying some pixels from one `BitmapData` instance to another, use [`copyPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) as it's *much* faster and also less confusing to work with.

I'll highlight the relevant arguments:

1. `sourceBitmapData:BitmapData` - the `BitmapData` instance to get the pixels from.
2. `sourceRect:Rectangle` - a `Rectangle` that will specify what portion of the source you want.
3. `destPoint:Point` - a `Point` representing where on the destination the source will be drawn.

So what you want to do is this:

```
// Define BitmapData.
var sourceBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 500, false, 0xFF0000);
var destinationBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200, 200, false, 0xFFFFFF);

// Add viewable Bitmap representation.
var view:Bitmap = new Bitmap(destinationBitmapData);
addChild(view);


// Define where pixels will be taken from off the source.
var clipRectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);

// Define where the pixels will be drawn at on the destination.
var destPoint:Point = new Point(); // Didn't catch where you wanted this to be drawn at - simply provide your own x, y here.

// Copy some pixels from sourceBitmapData across to destinationBitmapData.
destinationBitmapData.copyPixels(sourceBitmapData, clipRectangle, destPoint);
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt a bit more to the given question... destinationBmp is 200x200px size and source is 500x500 - destpoint 0,0 else than that uprated;)

Comment: @Marty : How should i access the sourceBitmapData. ( The bitmap is inside a movieclip say pic_Mc ). 
I don't know at which index it's available otherwise i think  Bitmap(pic_Mc.getChildAt(5)) might be useful. But i wonder, how should i access the bitmap in this case.

Comment: ok.. got it. This worked for me :  
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( pic_Mc.width, pic_Mc.height );
bd.draw( pic_Mc); ..........Thanks!